# How to keep submenu uncollapsed when user clicks link and is redirecting

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu with mainmenu/submenu that is collapsed by default

When user click on this mainmenu, submenu is displayed

When user click on submenu link, he is redirected but page is reload and mainmenu is collapsed

I would like to keep maimenu uncollapsed and submenu selected highlighted

I try with `stopPropagation` but it doesn't work

```
<a id="projectmainmenu" class="nav-link" href="#projectsubmenu" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i>Projets</a>
   <div id="projectsubmenu" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <ul  class="list-unstyled show">
             <li><a class="nav-link sub-menu" href="{% url 'project:index_projet' %}">
             <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ajouter un utilisateur</a></li>
             <li><a class="nav-link sub-menu" href="{% url 'project:index_projet' %}">
             <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ajouter un projet</a></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: If your page refreshed, your all codes are loaded again and your submenu will close.

Comment: You will need to read the URL of the page (`location.href`) and programmatically reopen the menu and submenu of the link that refers to it.

Comment: The easiest (but not nice) way is by using `?menu=show` at the end of your link. Then, open the submenu on each page with some javascript by reading the value of this parameter.

Comment: thanks for replying. What I've done for now, but is probably "bad practice" is to add JS in different html templates, for example: ```         $("#projectmainmenu").attr("aria-expended",true);
  $("#projectsubmenu").addClass("show");
  $("#projectsubmenu > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1)").css({"background-color":"#434648",}); ```